# Xcode 6.1.1 hangs when adding simulators using the devices panel - mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-mavericks

A project I started in Xcode 5 I opened after upgrading to Xcode 6.1.1. At some point the list of simulator devices became empty so tried to configure them.

When I go to the devices panel (from the Window menu) and click the "+" sign bottom left to display the "Create a new simulator" pane, when I click "Create" to create a simulator then Xcode hangs with a beach ball.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the Xcode application was deleted and reinstalled, the solution for this problem was rebooting the system.

Answer (score 2):

Have you renamed the app?
I had this issue because I renamed the app from "Xcode.app" to "Xcode 6.1.1.app".
When I did this all my simulators disappeared and if I tried to create a new one, Xcode would hang.
Once I named it back to "Xcode.app" all was well again.